# LNK1112: Module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' Visual Studio Command Prompt error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, x86

Before this is flagged as a duplicate: I **did** make sure that I loaded it in the correct version of VS.

```
C:\...>vcvars32
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.7.4
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

C:\...>clang  build/obj/Core/apu.c.o build/obj/Core/camera.c.o build/obj/Core/cheats.c.o build/obj/Core/debugger.c.o build/obj/Core/display.c.o build/obj/Core/gb.c.o build/obj/Core/joypad.c.o build/obj/Core/mbc.c.o build/obj/Core/memory.c.o build/obj/Core/printer.c.o build/obj/Core/random.c.o build/obj/Core/rewind.c.o build/obj/Core/rumble.c.o build/obj/Core/save_state.c.o build/obj/Core/sgb.c.o build/obj/Core/sm83_cpu.c.o build/obj/Core/sm83_disassembler.c.o build/obj/Core/symbol_hash.c.o build/obj/Core/timing.c.o build/obj/Windows/utf8_compat.c.o build/obj/SDL/font.c.o build/obj/SDL/gui.c.o build/obj/SDL/main.c.o build/obj/SDL/opengl_compat.c.o build/obj/SDL/shader.c.o build/obj/SDL/utils.c.o build/obj/OpenDialog/windows.c.o build/obj/SDL/audio/sdl.c.o build/obj/Windows/resources.o -o build/bin/SDL/sameboy.exe -lmsvcrt -lcomdlg32 -luser32 -lSDL2main -Wl,/MANIFESTFILE:NUL -Wl,/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -Wl,/subsystem:windows
build\obj\Windows\resources.o : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1112 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Emphasis on the vcvars**32**, the **'x86'**, and the ultimate problem of "target machine type **'x64'**".

I already tried completely deleting the `/build/` folder to ensure that artifacts of a previous build attempts were not causing problems. The project in question (SameBoy) is intended to be built for x86. I also tried completely redoing everything with `make` (after ensuring that I was in an x86 prompt), and I've been certain to link only to x86 libraries. All of the above encounters the same error.